# Distribute balance of a contract between owner`s tokens based on percentages?

Tags: solidity, balances

I have a contract and I have ether in it. How can I distribute balance of contract between owner`s tokens base on percentages?

Comment: What’s the actual issue? You know the total number of tokens, you know how many tokens each owner is. So you have the percentages. Make a `withdraw` function that will send a percentage calculated above to the token holder account.

Comment: I need send on all holders. And I don`t understand how to get their addresses and value tokens in one function. How interate balances.

Comment: that is not possible. Mappings cannot be iterated in Solidity. You would have to maintain an additional array of token holder addresses that you will have to iterate if you want to distribute to all token holders.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, because in documentation takes link on interable mapping http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In now day I have solution this task: https://github.com/poperechnyi1/iterable-Mapping-ERC20 I used iterable mapping: https://github.com/szerintedmi/solidity-itMapsLib

Answer (score 2):

If you still need an answer, try this excellent approach 
https://medium.com/@weka/dividend-bearing-tokens-on-ethereum-42d01c710657.

The key point here is that it is not you who distributes the ether among holders but holders should withdraw their share themselves.

Contract with ether should watch token transfers and adjust ether sums that are to be paid to those addresses.

The article describes 2 cases: one for fixed token supply and one for variable token supply.

Comment: Thank you very much. In now day I have resolve this problem: https://github.com/poperechnyi1/iterable-Mapping-ERC20